# Ubuntu 18.04 not loading NVIDIA drivers for a RTX card

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, cuda, secure-boot

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu 18.04 and tried to set it up with my new RTX 2080, but I was stuck with 640x480 (4:3) resolution. I've never had this issue with my old GTX.

So I've installed the 410.48 driver through the Cuda toolkit run file without any error. At first, nothing has changed, but when I've disabled secure boot and fired up Ubuntu, the driver loaded correctly and it automatically loaded at 1920x1080, which is my monitor's resolution.

But this only worked for the first boot. In every boot since the first one after changing the secure boot settings, the Nvidia driver didn't load correctly and I'm back stuck with the 640 x 480 resolution.

Some extra information:

1- If I check in Additional Drivers "Using NVIDIA driver metapackage from nvidia-driver-410(open source)" is selected under "NVIDIA Corporation: Unknown". Note that before installing the driver I got the "No additional drivers available" message.

2-

```
~$ sudo lshw -c video
  *-display                 
       deion: VGA compatible controller
       product: NVIDIA Corporation
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f6000000-f6ffffff memory:e0000000-efffffff memory:f0000000-f1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

3-When I try to open NVIDIA X Server Settings it loads for some seconds, disappear and nothing happens.

4-

```
~$ nvidia-smi
Failed to initialize NVML: Driver/library version mismatch
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that I've installed the driver two times accidentally. At first, I've installed the driver through a PPA repository. But when I installed the Cuda Toolkit with a run file, the graphics driver was installed a second time.

Uninstalling the ppa-installed driver worked for me!